# Is there a foreach in LINQ that returns the sequence instead of finishing the LINQ query?

Tags: linq, .net-core

I have a query during which I want to modify my items and continue with the query.

```
a.SelectMany(a => a.B)
    .Where(b => b.cList.All(c => !c.IsSelected))
    //I want to run foreach between those lines to set flag on b=>b.Flag = true
    .SelectMany(b => b.cList)
.ForEach(c =>  c.IsSelected = true;);
```

The issue is that I want to modify my `b` and continue with further projection. Is that achievable in one LINQ query?

Answer (score 3):

Well you *can* make projections that have side-effects. It's generally not a good idea (as LINQ is designed to be more functional) but it's easy enough to do:

```cs
a.SelectMany(a => a.B)
 .Where(b => b.cList.All(c => !c.IsSelected))
 .Select(b => { b.Flag = true; return b; }) 
 .SelectMany(b => b.cList)
 .ForEach(c => c.IsSelected = true);
```

Or you could write your own extension method to make it clearer:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSideEffect(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action) =>
    sequence.Select(item => { action(item); return item; });
...

// Use the extension method
a.SelectMany(a => a.B)
 .Where(b => b.cList.All(c => !c.IsSelected))
 .ExecuteSideEffect(b => b.Flag = true) 
 .SelectMany(b => b.cList)
 .ForEach(c => c.IsSelected = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one can work as well, but be careful with the performance caused by the `ToList()` method.

```
a.SelectMany(a => a.B)
    .Where(b => b.cList.All(c => !c.IsSelected))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(b => b.Flag = true);
```